# Searching for a pattern in dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, substring

I want to search python dictionary keys with some given pattern. This is more like a substring search, but with the char level. Below code is working fine, but I need some tuning, as it will have performace issues when we have thousands of keys. Hash Keys have sorted alphabets. By alphabetical sorting of keys, I mean every key (word) of the dictionary is sorted in itself, NOT the whole dictionary sorted on basis of keys. i.e. key can be `aaklm`, not the `kamal`.
Also, Is there any external library/API for this searching portion?

```
import re

def getKey(str, list):
    expr = re.compile(str)
    return [elem for elem in list if expr.match(elem)]


wordDict = {'AADFLORW':['value1'], 'AAAGRU': ['VAL1', 'SOME DIFFERENT VALUE']}
m = re.compile(u'[a-zA-Z]').findall('ADOLF')    # I'm searching ADOLF in the keys
pat = '.*' + '(.*)'.join(sorted(m)) + '.*'

for key in getKey(pat, wordDict.keys()):
    print(key)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795973/python-dictionary-search-values-for-keys-using-regular-expression this should help

Comment: If the keys are alphabetically sorted, how can they contain 'adolf'?

Comment: @Junuxx ADOLF is the input, I'm sorting the input as well and then checking in hash.

Answer (score 2):

As it is now, the main portion of the search will be in checking every key in `wordDict` against the pattern. One optimization I can think of is to reduce this search.

First I build "meta" dictionary, where keys are `frozenset` of characters of `wordDict`'s keys and values are lists of `wordDict` keys.

In `getKey()`, with this meta dictionary I check only keys where there's possibility of match (so not all of keys).

```
import re
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def getKey(string, pat, meta):
    k = ''.join(sorted(set(string)))
    expr = re.compile(pat)
    return [elem for elem in meta[frozenset(k)] if expr.match(elem)] # <--- here I search only valid keys (keys where there's possibility of match)

wordDict = {'AADFLORW':['value1'], 'AAAGRU': ['VAL1', 'SOME DIFFERENT VALUE']}

# build meta information about wordDict.keys()
# This could take a while!!!
meta = {}
for k in wordDict.keys():
    for p in powerset(set(k)):
        if p:
            meta.setdefault(frozenset(p), []).append(k)

# from pprint import pprint
# pprint(meta)

m = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]').findall('ADOLF')    # I'm searching ADOLF in the keys
pat = '.*' + '(.*)'.join(sorted(m)) + '.*'

for key in getKey('ADOLF', pat, meta):
    print(key)
```

Prints:

```
ADFLORW
```

---

For illustration, the "meta" dictionary now looks like this:

```
{frozenset({'A'}): ['AADFLORW', 'AAAGRU'],
 frozenset({'D'}): ['AADFLORW'],
 frozenset({'L'}): ['AADFLORW'],
 frozenset({'R'}): ['AADFLORW', 'AAAGRU'],
 frozenset({'W'}): ['AADFLORW'],
 frozenset({'O'}): ['AADFLORW'],
 frozenset({'F'}): ['AADFLORW'],
 frozenset({'A', 'D'}): ['AADFLORW'],
 frozenset({'A', 'L'}): ['AADFLORW'],
 frozenset({'A', 'R'}): ['AADFLORW', 'AAAGRU'],
 frozenset({'W', 'A'}): ['AADFLORW'],

...
```

It could be quite big, so now you are trading "space" for "speed".