# return value from dictionary with incomplete key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have stumbled across a problem with python dictionary keys.

For instance, I have a dictionary:

```
foo = {
    'longkey': 1,
    'shortkey': 2,
}
```

How can I return `2` from `foo` using just the string `'short'`?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795973/python-dictionary-search-values-for-keys-using-regular-expression] .Please check this link.

Comment: You would have to iterate through all key-value-pairs of the dict to find that key or you use another data structure (maybe from external library) to find it more efficiently.

Comment: keys = [key for key in foo if key.startswith('short')] Use this

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are the actual values of `longkey` and `shortkey`? Can you not just assign `foo["short"] = 2` and access your dictionary normally? Having to iterate over the keys defeats the purpose of a dictionary.

Comment: One of the purposes of a dictionary is to have hashed keys, and thus O(1) access to the data. If you need to loop over the keys to find the one you need, then this defeats the purpose of a dictionary. Can you explain in more details why you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return `2` just with the string `short`, you can do like this:

```
for k,v in foo.items():
    if 'short' in k:
        print(v)
```

This will print the `value` of key `short` if any key of dictionary contains the word `short`.

If you want that the `key` should start with `short`, you can try this:

```
for k,v in foo.items():
    if k.startswith('short'):
        print(v)
```